# Automatically generating Guids in Sybase

Tags: sybase

I have a table with 42 million records. 32 million have a null value and I would like to generate a new guid for each one. Should I do this in batches?

Also, going forward, I would like a new guid added to the field on the insert of a new record. What is the best way to do this?

The field is not the primary key, which is an auto-incrementing integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried an insert trigger?

Comment: Thanks @Carly. Yes I have but +1 for your answer, since you are a new user.

Answer (score 0):

There is a newid() function to generate a guid. Your column should be varchar(32) (or varbinary(16)) or bigger.
You should run the update in batches to avoid filling up the transaction log e.g

```
set rowcount 10000
while exists (select 1 from mytab where myid is null)
  update mytab set myid = newid() where myid is null
set rowcount 0
```

You don't need a trigger - just bind the function as a column default. There is an example in the Sybase docs.